# How to prevent an application from not displaying multiple cancel messagebox's?

Tags: mfc, messagebox

I am having a `propertysheet` and it has three pages (page1, page2, page3) respectively.For which I added as messagebox whenever Cancel button is pressed or [X] is clicked or <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed.

Steps followed:

1.Ran the application.

2. Pressed Cancel button and message box is popped up. (Did not cancel the messagebox).
3. Now go to the taskbar and right click on the application icon and click "close window". Exactly here the problem arose; i.e, one more message box window is popped up.

Actually this should not happen, right? It should be restricted to only one message box.

```
//This is being triggered when close window or cancel button is pressed.

BOOL OnQueryCancel()
{

    if(IDOK == ::MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"Closing the application",
                            L"Warning", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONWARNING))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

How can I prevent from not displaying multiple messagebox's? I should show focus to the already opened messagebox.

Comment: How do I know that whether messagebox is already opened or not?

Comment: That's not a real question. Show us some code, preferably a [short, self contained, correct compilable example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera Please find the modified post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use AfxMessageBox, which makes it easier in MFC. Second, this is normal operation in Windows -- it's just responding to the close messages. I would add a variable to indicate the box is displayed already:

```
//Part of your class
BOOL m_bIsPromptActive;

BOOL OnQueryCancel()
{
  if( !m_bIsPromptActive)
  {
    m_bIsPromptActive = TRUE;

    if(IDOK == ::MessageBox(m_hWnd, L"Closing the application",
                            L"Warning", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONWARNING))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    m_bIsPromptActive = FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
     // Message is already displayed. Set the focus to this window
     ::SetFocus( m_hWnd ); // or this->SetFocus();
     // You can also look at ::BringWindowToFront()
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It worked like charm.Here in the else part you are setting focus to the parent window. Can we set focus to the message box instead of setting focus to the parent window.

Comment: You can't set the focus to the MessageBox because you don't have the handle to it. However, the MB is a child of the form (you passed the m_hWnd) and since it's modal, the parent will give it the focus. (You can retrieve the MB handle but not worth the trouble).